# Looking for the right words/phrases to refer an 'earlier'/'later' line in text

Tags: phrase-request

In a paragraph, I know I can refer to text by phrases like 'as said earlier', 'as mentioned above', etc. However I am wondering what would be the right word if I want to say 'This is not the first time this word is used in this text. The first use is in a *_* line.' What are the right words? Above/below? Earlier/later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Infra* (below) and *supra* (above) are also frequently used. You can just put them between brackets after the word you used before.

Other possibilities: *aforementioned*, *above(-)mentioned*, *previously mentioned*, *as stated before*... *Above* and *earlier* are also correct.

Comment: +1 for *aforementioned*, which (not with OP's exact surrounding text) would almost always be my first choice.

Comment: Again +1 for aforementioned, although I'm dubious about *infra* and *supra*. These are not particularly common, at least outside of academia and law.

Comment: @Matt probably you are right! I read mainly academic texts.

Answer (score 2):

*Above* and *earlier* are fine choices, as is "first use is in a *previous* line". Mix and match to suite your taste, though "above" should avoided if something is to be in a book/booklet/pamphlet form as "above" might not end up being applicable after final typesetting.